# received buffer first character is null in socket at the server side

Tags: sockets

i am writing socket programming at server side.

```
 size=recv(src_port,buffer,256,0);
         printf("%d \n",buffer[0]);
         printf("The message the server recieved %s \n",buffer);
         if(size==-1){
         printf("The server is unable to recieve message from client%d\n",src_port);
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(size==0){
                   printf("The server is recieving 0 byts messgae from client%d\n",src_port);
                   return 0;
                }
                else{
                    if(send(cl_port,buffer,256,0)==-1){
                            printf("unable to send from client%d\n",src_port);
                           return 0;
                       }
                       return 1;
             }
```

the first character is 0 i.e its is null.
why is it that the input buffer is zero ??
Does there any reasons like that the memory of buffer is not accessible??

Comment: Possibly because you were sending 0? Note 0 is a very valid data to be sent and received on a socket. Do not confuse it with return value of `read` or `recv`.

Comment: as i have used printf("%d",buffer[0]) and it is printing 0 which is the ascii value of null.basicaaly which means that the first character is null.

Comment: You are failing to correctly handle the 'size' return from the recv() call.  Until you do that correctly, everything after it is pointless and/or UB.

Comment: today after restarting my computer it is running properly.The process is waiting at the recv() function..i dont know what was the problem.but at last it is running.